# cannot use package makeidx

Tags: pdftex, makeidx

I want to use the package `makeidx`, but I can't.
When I comment out the `\usepackage{makeidx}` everything is ok, but I don't have index at the end.

Note

`\index{animal}` at the end.

I have this source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuScript{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuScript{bold}{U}{eus}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\CMcal}{}
\let\CMcal=\mathcal
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{shadow}

\usepackage{carom,epic,eepic,hetarom}

\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%%PDF-compatible mode
%\usepackage{xymtexps}%%PostScript-compatible mode
%\wedgehashedwedge%global declaration



\begin{document}
\cyclohexanev{2B==Cl;4E==S}
X \shadowbox{This is a shadowbox}
Y \shabox{This is a shabox} Z

\cyclohexanev{}
\cyclohexanev{ 1==1 ; %
2D==2D ; %
3A==3A ; %
4B==4B ; %
5Sa==5Sa ; 5Sb==5Sb ; %
6SA==6SA ; 6SB==6SB}

\index{animal}


$\bigcurlyvee$

\[ \mathcal{A} = \EuScript{A} \neq \CMcal{A} \]
\begin{theindex}
\end{theindex}

\end{document}
```

AND I GOT THIS ERROR

> Command Line:   bibtex.exe "ideje7" Startup Folder:
>   C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: ideje7.aux I found no \citation commands---while
>   reading file ideje7.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading
>   file ideje7.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file
>   ideje7.aux (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Command Line:   makeindex.exe "ideje7.idx" Startup Folder:
>   C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl
>
> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai
>   support). Scanning input file ideje7.idx....done (1 entries accepted,
>   0 rejected). Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons). Generating output
>   file ideje7.ind....done (5 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written
>   in ideje7.ind. Transcript written in ideje7.ilg.
>
> Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1
>   "C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\ideje7.tex" Startup Folder:
>   C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl
>
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
>   entering extended mode (C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/TH0dipl/ideje7.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2014/05/01> Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68
>   languages loaded.
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\article.cls Document Class:
>   article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty For
>   additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty))
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty))
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\stmaryrd\stmaryrd.sty)
>   (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\makeidx.sty
>
> ! LaTeX Error: \see undefined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.41 \renewcommand*\see
>                    [2]{\emph{\seename} #1} ?
> ```
>
> Process has been killed ...

Comment: You have no `\makeindex` in the `\preamble` and the index is usually printed with `\printindex`, which does `\begin{theindex}...\end{theindex}` internally. So you're using `makeidx` not correctly.  All the other stuff with `cyclohexa...` is not necessary in order to show the minimal problem, I think

Comment: I tried your example, kicked the unnecessary chemistry stuff and **can** compile it...

Comment: can you give me the source here you can compile?

Comment: There is no way really other than posting code as an answer or pastebin, but I don't have a pastebin account. I can compile even the full document, there's no error for me. If your code breaks at `\usepackage{makeidx}` then something different is wrong, perhaps a broken installation

Comment: Well, the answer will do. Can you post it as an answer then?

Comment: If your compilation breaks at the point of `\usepackage{makeidx}` there is another problem, that a potential posting of my working variant cannot solve

Comment: Just post what has compiled for you in an answer?

Comment: The code as shown produces no error.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the comments 
For others benefit the mwe adapted like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex % make an index

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuScript{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuScript{bold}{U}{eus}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\CMcal}{}
\let\CMcal=\mathcal
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{shadow}

\usepackage{carom,epic,eepic,hetarom}

\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%%PDF-compatible mode
%\usepackage{xymtexps}%%PostScript-compatible mode
%\wedgehashedwedge%global declaration

\begin{document}

    \cyclohexanev{2B==Cl;4E==S} \index{Shadowboxes} % add to index
    X \shadowbox{This is a shadowbox}
    Y \shabox{This is a shabox} Z

    \cyclohexanev{} \index{Pretty pic} % add to index
    \cyclohexanev{ 1==1 ; %
        2D==2D ; %
        3A==3A ; %
        4B==4B ; %
        5Sa==5Sa ; 5Sb==5Sb ; %
        6SA==6SA ; 6SB==6SB}

    $\bigcurlyvee$ \index{(What a character :-)} % add to index

    \[ \mathcal{A} = \EuScript{A} \neq \CMcal{A} \] \index{A Formula} % add to index

%\begin{theindex} % Not needed here use \printindex
%\end{theindex}   % Not needed here use \printindex
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Produces on last page (2) an index like this
 [image]